# java world terminology

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I come from the .NET world, so I will ask in .NET terms in order to understand what is the java-world terms. I have experience with java.
I need to create asolution with two projects: library project and web application.
The library project uses hibernate and the web application should have reference to the library application.

I am using intellij and I saw there are various things like project and module. I don't know this terminology - can anyone explain me what king of 'projects' I need?

I saw that if I create a new project while working on project it opens a new window.
While I add a new module it adds the module project in the big project.

Comment: I'd say it's rather an IntelliJ thing than a Java thing.

Comment: please note that a 'Module' in IntelliJ is equivalent to 'Project' in Eclipse, and IntelliJ 'Project' is Eclipse's 'Workspace' more or less...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I am a heavy IntelliJ IDEA user I always start from [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) project, which I then import to IDE.

In maven you create one parent project (with `pom` packaging) and two submodules: one with `war` packaging and dependent one with `jar` (default). After importing you'll see two modules in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

The terminology is IntelliJ's rather than a Java standard. (Other IDEs use similar terminology)

There is not much more to projects and modules than you have realised already.  A single projects which is opened at once contains several modules which break up your work logically.  A single modules can appear in multiple projects, but this can be more confusing than useful.

You can have one project with one module which is the simplest way to start.

You may want to look at using maven as this a portable way to manage your dependencies and build your project (all IDEs support maven and it can be run stand alone)